# how to delete currently clicked html div tag angular 4

Tags: angular, angular5

below is my div tag

```js
removeObject(event) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(event.target);
    event.target.hidden = true;
    //event.target.classList.add('class3');
  }
```

```html
<div class="col" (click)="removeObject($event)">Rate Limit</div>
```

which i want to replace with a text box on click

Comment: What you want is after clicked and disapear the div?

Comment: yes I want to replace the div tag with text box after click event

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1):

Use `*ngIf` for that like this. You need a variable in your component called `hidden` for example.

```
<div class="col" *ngIf="!hidden" (click)="removeObject($event)">Rate Limit</div>
<input name='limit' *ngIf="hidden">
```

And your ts method

```
removeObject(event) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(event.target);
    this.hidden = !this.hidden;
}
```

Something like this. If you save the value of your input or something you can set hidden to false again and the div will show or what ever you require.

Comment: will you please explain it

Comment: `hidden` is gonna be a boolean that you need to define in your ts which will be `false` by default. Element will be displayed if `*ngIf` is true. When element is clicked `removeObject` method will toggle the value of hidden variable, making `!hidden` false and div disappear.

Comment: Then how will you make the hidden to come again? Instead you can use  contentEditable property in div, where on click of the div, it will turn to textbox(editable) and on click outside it will look like a div.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing the div and showing the textbox, you can use the "contentEditable" property to toggle between editable and non-editable div.

There is no need to maintain one more textbox here.

```
removeObject(event) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(event.target);
    event.target.contentEditable= !event.target.contentEditable;
    //event.target.classList.add('class3');
  }
```

Comment: can you please explain it with the complete code, as I may not be able to implement it.

Comment: <div class="test"  contenteditable="true">Test it</div> Just create an html and try this. contenteditable will make the div act like an input. You can have the specific styles to make the input look like textbox / textarea etc.,  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_contenteditable.asp